Can we find a neighbourhood around a singular point such that the given expression is undefined in the neighbourhood too?
I was solving the following differential equation:
$$x^2y''+(1+x)y'+3y = 0$$
I tried to express the equation in the form:
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y = 0$$
where $p(x) = \frac{1+x}{x^2}$ and $q(x) = \frac{3}{x^2}$.
The exclusion of the point $x=0$ for the second equation is understood but my question is that does there exist a $\delta$-neighborhood of $0$, such that the second equation is not defined in this neighborhood too? ($\delta > 0$)

You should ask yourself when does it make sense to say that a function is unbounded in the neighborhood of a point. Certainly not when it is not defined in the whole neighborhood...

Choose any interval near but bounded away from $0$, no matter how close to $0$ it is. Do the theorems you are relying on break down on this interval? No, the functions are smooth on that interval, and while the values and derivatives may be quite large, they are still bounded. The DE has solutions which extend to this interval. No matter how close you are to $0$, the solutions extend to the region. The only place it breaks down is at $0$ itself.
